# Cannot install Commerce Commerce License 7.x-1.3 in drupal 7.41

Tags: 7, commerce

Not able to enable [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) 7.x-1.3 or 7.x-1.x-dev
Tried several times each time on clean Drupal install.

Running
Apache, MySQL, PHP 5.6
clean standard install of Drupal 7.41

All dependent modules are available
Enabled all commerce modules with success
Commerce 7.x-1.11

All dependent modules are available
Trying to enable in admin/modules
Commerce License 7.x-1.3
No error message, not installed, shows uninstalled in admin/modules
No log info.
No changes in DB system table.

I have no problem enabling other modules.
Other modules uses same environment and Drupal version so how can it be
environment problem or Drupal problem?

Have checked PHP extensions and settings and these seems to be according to Drupal standards https://www.drupal.org/requirements

Comment: So you're enabling the module but the next time the modules page reloads it just shows it as disabled? I'd start by enabling [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and [Commerce Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_devel) to see if you can get some sort of error message. Also, turn on as much error reporting as you can.

Comment: I also recommend heading out to the issue queue for commerce_license to see if others are having similar issues.